# 'While Statement' for jobs running oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, jobs

I have a cursor to get the data of the cursors in state RUNNING or SCHEDULED

```
CURSOR cursorJobStatus IS
     SELECT d.job_name, d.state
       FROM dba_scheduler_jobs d
       WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(d.job_name, '^(P_|S_|B_)')
         AND d.state IN ('RUNNING','SCHEDULED');
```

how i can execute a loop while exist data in 'cursorJobStatus', That is, as long as there are 'jobs' in state RUNNING or SCHEDULED?

i tried with this 'for' but its not works, because only go in the 'for' by the records it finds and does not ask all the time for the state of the cursor

```
FOR lrtJobStatus IN cursorJobStatus LOOP
   BEGIN
     DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(5);           
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN                    
       EXIT;                  
   END;
   EXIT WHEN cursorJobStatus%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
declare
   l_job_running pls_integer;
begin
   loop
      begin
         select 1
           into l_job_running
           from dual
          where exists (select 1
                   from dba_scheduler_jobs d
                  where regexp_like(d.job_name, '^(P_|S_|B_)')
                    and d.state in ('RUNNING', 'SCHEDULED'));
      exception
         when no_data_found then
            l_job_running := 0;
      end;

      exit when l_job_running = 0;

      dbms_lock.sleep(5);

   end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried making an anonymous block which will check for the current jobs  running and will continue to execute till there is a job which is executing. I guess you can achieve your objective the same way.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
var1 number default '1';
begin
loop
dbms_output.put_line('inside the loop');
select count(*) into var1 from dba_jobs_running;
exit when var1=0;
dbms_output.put_line('job/jobs are executing');
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line('anonymous block completes');
end;
```